# Conda CommandNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, macos, conda, zsh

Well, when I use command:

> ​conda activate -m work

I take the result:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

I found the temporary fix:

> eval "$(command conda 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

But, that solution work once. When I restart console, that problem was returned.
Any ideas how I may fix that?

Comment: You need to place the configuration into one of your zsh startup files. Have a look at _man zsh_, chapter _INVOCATION_, which says which files a new zsh processes under which conditions.

Comment: BTW, your "solution" does not look very reliable to me. It uses _shell.bash_, and though i don't use conda, I would be surprised if a file with the name _bash_ in it would be suitable for zsh.